# What is the greylist.txt in a kmod rpm package

Tags: centos, kernel, kernel-module, rhel

Many device driver appear as a `kmod-<drivername>` rpm package in CentOS/RHEL, and there is always a greylist.txt in these package, with some kernel symbol as its contents. Here are an example:

```
[root@localhost download]# rpm -ql kmod-qed
/etc/depmod.d/qed.conf
/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64
/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64/extra
/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64/extra/qed
/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64/extra/qed/qed.ko
/usr/share/doc/kmod-qed/greylist.txt

[root@localhost download]# cat /usr/share/doc/kmod-qed/greylist.txt 
bitmap_clear
bitmap_set
__fentry__
ioremap_wc
pci_enable_msi_range
pci_enable_msix_range
pci_ioremap_bar
pci_is_pcie
pci_read_config_byte
pci_read_config_word
pci_save_state
release_firmware
request_firmware
__smp_mb__after_atomic
__stack_chk_fail
synchronize_irq
tasklet_init
__tasklet_schedule
vzalloc
x86_dma_fallback_dev
zlib_inflate
zlib_inflateEnd
zlib_inflateInit2
zlib_inflate_workspacesize
```

I guess it must have something to do with the kernel ABI whitelist, but what exactly is the purpose of this `greylist` file? and how was it generated while packaging the kmod rpm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a better answer I can tell you that since it is under `/usr/share/doc` it should just be documentation and nothing of consequence. I wish I could tell you the purpose and how it was generated. I can only see that it was not generated during packaging. You can see in the Spec file that it is included as a static source. (Grab the SRPM and have a look.)